# Way to write a bootable CD to a partition?

Tags: linux, partitioning, arch-linux, bootable-media

Arch-Linux comes with the best recovery CD I have ever come across. Although I don't always have it with me, so I want to have it on a partition.

What I would like to do is have this CD on a partition on my hard drive that I can boot from, without having the CD with me. Because sometimes I might not have it, and the recovery kernel is broken (example: a recent `mkinitcpio` kernel build). Is there a way, either using `dd`, or another external program to write it to a partition? Or is there a way to emulate a disk with just the .ISO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `dd` will help you make the partition which is capable of making the system boot through it. We are basically doing the same thing to the USB drive to make it bootable.
- However, you cannot tell you `BIOS` to boot through a partition, and hence you will need to configure your `GRUB` to boot through that partion using:

> rootnoverify (hd0,n)
>   chainloader +1
>   boot

Where `n` is the partition number.

Comment: I use Syslinux, but I know how to configure that aswell to boot other partitions

Comment: So, then point it to that partition to boot and it should work! :)

Comment: Bacon Bits' answer is better, but just posting links to articles isnt very good, so you get best answer for atleast providing information in your own words :)

Answer (score 2):

Based on [this article](http://lifehacker.com/5754941/how-to-boot-a-linux-live-image-without-burning-it-to-a-cd) you can use Unetbootin to accomplish this.  I've never tried it myself, however.

Comment: Unetbootin only wants to install to my existing partition, not an alternate partition

Comment: Actually, it might even overwrite your main MBR so I would suggest you take a great caution with it.