# Install windows 10 onto a laptop without access to USB booting

Tags: boot, usb, ssd, bios

I've got a laptop with no OS on it and I want to install Windows 10 onto it but I can't boot from USB as it is not enabled in the BIOSand I can't change it because I don't have the BIOS admin password.

I've tried taking the SSD out and putting it in a caddy and burning a Windows 10 ISO to it from another laptop then putting the SSD back into the laptop and booting it. The installation starts but fails straight away with a "Select driver to install" error... "A media driver your computer needs is missing".

Is there any other way of installing Windows 10 on this laptop?

Comment: You can clear the BIOS password on most devices by temporary removing the CMOS battery

Comment: If clearing the BIOS password does not work, let us know your exact computer model.

Comment: Tried the CMOS battery trick but didn't work. Model is an HP EliteBook 840 G6

Comment: Why not ask whoever set the BIOS password?

Comment: "Why not ask whoever set the BIOS password?" They were a third party supplier who have gone bust so nobody to ask

Comment: Then you're going to have to get in touch with HP. No-one else can unlock one of those legitimately. There are some "you pays your money, you takes your chance" replacement BIOS chip suppliers on eBay, at your own risk.

Comment: does the laptop have a cd/dvd drive?

Comment: You can't "burn" an install ISO to a partition, as that's not how WinPE [Windows Install ISO] boots _(booting WinPE from a partition is more [complex](https://superuser.com/a/1698320/529800), requiring the ADK and using `MakeWinPeMedia` to create the UFD filesystem)_. **Easiest way to do this:** Attach drive to another PC _(externally or internally)_ → Boot Install USB on that PC → Install Windows to the laptop's drive → Once Windows boots to OOBE _(where user interaction is required to configure settings, create a user, etc.)_, shutdown the PC → Reinstall drive in the laptop → Boot the laptop

Answer (score 1):

Sorted it.  Downloaded Microsoft's Windows 10 Media Creation Tool and downloaded a new Windows 10 ISO. Took my SSD out of the target laptop, put it in a caddy and connected it to my windows 10 laptop. Used Rufus to burn the ISO to my SSD.  used MiniTool Partition wizard to create another two partitions on the SSD, shrunk the initial partition to 6gb for booting and then created another 6gb and the rest (240 odd) for the new installation. Copied the files inside of the ISO to the other 6gb partition. Put the SSD back into the target Laptop and booted, when the new installation starts hit shift + f10 which opens a command prompt. type in DISKPART and then LIST VOL and note the drive of you copied ISO files. type EXIT and the go to the drive of your ISO files e.g. E: and then run setup.exe. You are then able to do a full installation to your big partition.